# AutoIt _IsPressed not woking in loop

Tags: autoit

I am having trouble with the following code. I am trying to have the loop bail and go to a Setup() Function if the TAB key is pressed. However when I press TAB nothing happens, it just continues the loop, please help!

```
While -1
    While -1
        WinActivate($PID)
        Sleep(1000)
        Send("Hello")
        $timer = TimerInit()
        While -1
            PixelSearch($searchL,$searchT,$searchR,$searchB,"0x" & Hex($color,6),10,1)
--->        If _IsPressed("09",$dll) Then ExitLoop 3 ;HERE IS THE CODE THAT IS NOT WORKING
            If @error <> 1 Then ExitLoop
            If TimerDiff($timer) > 1000 Then
                Sleep(1000)
                WinActivate($PID)
                ExitLoop 2
            EndIf
        Wend
        $timer = TimerInit()
        MouseMove($shade[0], $shade[1])
        While -1
            PixelSearch($shade[0]-10,$shade[1]-10,$shade[0]+10,$shade[1]+10,"0x" & Hex($color,6),10,1)
--->        If _IsPressed("09",$dll) Then ExitLoop 3 ;HERE IS THE CODE THAT IS NOT WORKING
            If @error = 1 Then ExitLoop
            If TimerDiff($timer) > 5000 Then
                Sleep(1000)
                WinActivate($PID)
                Exitloop 2
            EndIf
         Wend
    Wend
 Wend
Setup()
EndFunc
```

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having a problem with the `$dll` variable. It's probably not initialised. Just get rid of it. This little example works just fine:

```
#include <Misc.au3>

MsgBox( 0, "1 loop", "Now testing with 1 loop." )
While -1
    If _IsPressed("09") Then
        MsgBox( 0, "_IsPressed", "You pressed the TAB key." )
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
WEnd

MsgBox( 0, "3 loops", "Now testing with 3 loops." )
While -1
    While -1
        While -1
            If _IsPressed("09") Then
                MsgBox( 0, "_IsPressed", "You pressed the TAB key." )
                ExitLoop 3
            EndIf
        WEnd
    WEnd
WEnd

MsgBox( 0, "_IsPressed", "Test done." )
```